# Google Storage REST get with axios

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, axios, google-cloud-storage

I want to get a list of images in a bucket using REST and axios.

ref: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#list-objects-json

The documentation gives this curl request

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH2_TOKEN" \
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME/o"
```

reqConfig: this is a token I use in my REST firestore queries to authenticate the user. I'm using that same token for here. I'm guessing it's the problem but not sure how to fix it.

My result is consistently 404 for a bucket path that I know exists, using the URL from their docs. I should be getting a json list of the files in the bucket.

> Error: Request failed with status code 404

Where am I going wrong?

```
export async function getCompanyStorage(context, apikey, companyId) {
  const url = `https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/uploads/${companyId}/o?key=${apikey}`;
  
  const cookies = nookies.get(context);

  const reqConfig = {
    headers: new Headers({
      Authorization: "Bearer " + cookies.token,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }),
  };

  const result = axios
    .get(url, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${reqConfig}` } })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("error using axios", error);
    });
}
```

Edit: a path to a bucket in the firebase console looks like this

> gs://projectname.appspot.com/uploads/WhmDZyQdLVk7n0qR7aTg

Comment: 404 means not found.  Check your URL.  We can't see what's in your variables or the contents of your bucket.  Your question should explain what you expect this code to do, and the source data that you're working with.

Comment: @DougStevenson I don't have much faith in the validity of that 404 given I'm using the same URL as their docs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reviewing the documentation you linked to.  In particular:

> - OAUTH2_TOKEN is the access token you generated in Step 1.
> - BUCKET_NAME is the name of the bucket whose objects you want to list. For example, my-bucket.
>
> You can use a prefix=PREFIX query string parameter to limit results to
> objects that have the specified prefix.

Your URL does not contain the name of the bucket as required by the URL pattern.  Use the unique name of the bucket where you see "BUCKET_NAME".  It looks like, given your example, that it would be "projectname.appspot.com".  BUCKET_NAME is **not** the path of the object within that bucket.  If you want to list files under the "uploads" prefix, then you would use the `prefix` query string parameter to specify that, as documented in the last line of the quoted text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to create Get request with axios for Google Cloud Storage

```
export const UploadVideo = async (form_data, file, signedurl, asset_uuid) => {
    let resultState = { state: '', data: {} };
    console.log(signedurl)
/*
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("PUT", signedurl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/octet-stream");
    xhr.send(file);
*/
    let config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        },
    };

    await axios.get(signedurl, file, config).then(function (response) {
        resultState.state = 'success';
    }).catch(function (error) {
        resultState.state = 'error';
        resultState.data.message = error.message;
        window.toastr.error(error.message);

        console.log(error)
    })

    return resultState;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like it would get a list of images and the "signed URL" is the probably the biggest problem.